# How to test the ordering of elements in a Collection in JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit

I want to verify my ordering algorithm of a collection in Java with JUnit tests. If I input "B","C","A" into a collection and want it sorted (alphabetically for example), what is the proper way to test this with JUnit ?

I implemented the Comparable interface and want to make sure my sorting is working.

I suppose this question could be broaden beyond Java or JUnit to general testing in any language.

Comment: Do you mean you implemented a sort algorithm and want to test that the collection is properly sorted?

Comment: you should traverse the array and check that every N element is lesser than the N+1 element

Comment: Here is a solution from another topic : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42023087/3062707

Comment: you can write a func like shuffle arr then sort then assert sorted do those steps more than 1000

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would create another collection with the values in the *expected* order, and then just check that the results match.

But to be honest, if you're just trying to check your implementation of `IComparable` and *not* some sort algorithm, I would *just* make assertions about the results of calling `compareTo`. It'll be simpler to write the tests and *much* simpler to understand any failures.

(If a sorting test fails, that would just mean that *one* of the many comparisons did the wrong thing. It wouldn't help you work out *which* comparison did the wrong thing.)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I got exactly your question. When it comes to the technical side of writing the test, you could use something along these lines (example uses [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) though):

```
import java.util.Collection;

import org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInOrder;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void collectionTest() {
        final Collection<String> actual = Lists.newArrayList("AAA", "ABC", "BBB", "AZZ");
        Assert.assertThat(actual, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains("AAA", "ABC", "AZZ", "BBB"));
    }
}
```

Result of running this one:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable containing ["AAA", "ABC", "AZZ", "BBB"]
     got: <[AAA, ABC, BBB, AZZ]>

    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:778)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:736)
    at ...
```

If your question was more philosophical then there are two other answers...

Answer (score 1):

I would say start with special cases :

1. An empty input
2. An input in reverse order
3. An input in order

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use JUnit, or any other testing framework, it doesn't matter. Problem about unit testing is you want to test your class behaviour (this is why is UNIT testing). The test class itself should not implement Comparable, is it your class that should, but for the sake of testing this is irrelevant.

Think of a list of scenarios that you want to test.

For example, submit "B","C","A", and make sure that what you return is equal to "A","B","C". Make sure that if you submit an ordered list, you return the same ordered list. Make sure that it handles correctly null input, empty input, and boundary cases ("A","B","A" could be a good one to test). You should have one test for each case, and your assertions should check exactly a specific case in every test.